# Docker rm returning ContainerNotFoundException after successfully removing container

Tags: c#, docker, rm, docker-api, docker-engine

I am using a C# API that talks to DockerEngine [(Docker.DotNet)](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/) to do some things, but notably, in this case, removed a stopped container. Here is my code:

```cs
foreach (var container in RunningContainers)
{
    if (container.State == "dead" || container.State == "exited")
    {
        long exitType = Client.Containers.InspectContainerAsync(container.ID).Result.State.ExitCode;

        if (exitType != 0)
        {
            badExitCodeCount++;
        }
        Client.Containers.RemoveContainerAsync(container.ID, new ContainerRemoveParameters()).Wait();
    }
}
```

Note that in this case `RunningContainers` still includes the stopped containers and hasn't had its state refreshed yet.

Here's the bug. The API successfully calls out to DockerEngine after executing `RemoveContainerAsync`, the container is removed from my local Docker Containers. Then shortly after the code moves on, a Docker "No such container" response is received, throwing an exception.

Any ideas about what's going on here?

Comment: Which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Sorry, the RemoveContainerAsync call.

Comment: Why do you use DockerEngine's async API in synchronous fashion?

Comment: @PeterCsala This code lies within a server tick

Comment: @zkatancik I do believe that you can still use `async void` to be able to utilize `await` ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260486/is-it-okay-to-attach-async-event-handler-to-system-timers-timer))

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied within multiple threads running the method at the same time, tricky race condition I missed.